# Gentoo Linux global environments for root

Tags: linux, environment-variables, root, gentoo

I'm confused with setting variables in /etc/env.d directory. When I write "echo $PATH" from user - it's print me all variables that set it myself. But from root I see one... Where should I set variables for root?

Answer (score 1):

You should set `ROOTPATH` instead of `PATH` in your /etc/env.d/* files.